# How to digitally sign a PDF document with visible signature and text using Java

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature, pfx

I am trying to digitally sign a PDF file using `PDFBox Library` using Java with visible text to appear on a signature field like the attached image. I tried the following code and I get the following warning,

> WARN org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField -
> Appearance generation for signature fields not yet implemented - you
> need to generate/update that manually

Following is the code,

```
PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("input.pdf"));
PDDocumentCatalog pDDocumentCatalog = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pDDocumentCatalog.getAcroForm();
PDSignatureField pDSignatureField = (PDSignatureField) pDAcroForm.getField("signatureField");
PDSignature pDSignature = new PDSignature();

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("pfxfile.pfx"), "password".toCharArray());
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("pfxfile.pfx"));
pDSignature.setContents(bytes);

pDSignatureField.setValue(pDSignature);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.pdf");
pDDocument.saveIncremental(fileOutputStream);
```

[image: Digital Signature]

So what is I am doing wrong here? Or are there any solution apart from PDFBox?

Comment: That's not the way signing is done, please have a look at the CreateVisibleSignature*.java examples in the source code download (examples subproject).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I checked it and it's huge code set. But how to sign in a specific field? Is there a way that you can show me?

Comment: Yes it is big :-( The example does also have code for signing an existing signature field. You need to know its name (if you can't find it, use PDFDebugger and hover over the field, or share the file). Search for "findExistingSignature" in the code.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you very much. Is that code in the same class?

Comment: But I can't find a proper example how to do that. Can you guide me?

Comment: I already guided you. I won't do a zoom session. Download the giant source code zip file. Then search for the two CreateVisibleSignature*.java in the download (better, open the entire project in your IDE). Find CreateVisibleSignature2.java and try to run it. (make the modifications so that it uses your own keystore). Also download PDFDebugger and run it with your file to get the field name. Or share the file and I'll tell you the name of the field. Yes, "findExistingSignature" is in that class. Press CTRL-F to find it. If you need more help, ask specifically which step you need help for.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Sure. I will check that. Thank you very much.

Comment: *"Or are there any solution apart from PDFBox"* - for software recommendations please ask on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with iText. This is a working solution using `iText 7`. You can check more from their [examples](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signatures-chapter-1).

```
public static void digitalSignature(String sourceFile, String signatureFieldName, String outputFile, Certificate[] certificateChain, PrivateKey privateKey, String digestAlgorithm,
        String bouncyCastleProvider, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard cryptoStandardSubFilter, String reason, String location)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
    PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(outputFile), new StampingProperties());

    // Create the signature appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance pdfSignatureAppearance = pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance()
            .setReason(reason)
            .setLocation(location);

    // This name corresponds to the name of the field that already exists in the document.
    pdfSigner.setFieldName(signatureFieldName);

    pdfSignatureAppearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);

    IExternalSignature iExternalSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(privateKey, digestAlgorithm, bouncyCastleProvider);
    IExternalDigest iExternalDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

    // Sign the document using the detached mode, CMS, or CAdES equivalent.
    pdfSigner.signDetached(iExternalDigest, iExternalSignature, certificateChain, null, null, null, 0, cryptoStandardSubFilter);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(bouncyCastleProvider);

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("path/to/keystore/file"), "password".toCharArray());
    String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
    Certificate[] certificateChain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);

    digitalSignature("path/to/input.pdf", "Signature Field Name", "path/to/output.pdf", certificateChain, privateKey,
            DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, bouncyCastleProvider.getName(), PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
            "Reason", "Location");
}
```